# botocore.exceptions.ClientError An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the GetObject operation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, boto3

While running the following code:

```
import boto3
BUCKET = 'bwd-plfb'

s3 = boto3.client('s3',use_ssl = False)

resp = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket = BUCKET )

s3.download_file(BUCKET,'20171018/OK/OK_All.zip','test.zip')
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
   botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred 
   (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the GetObject operation: The request 
   signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check 
   your key and signing method.
```

What I've tried so far:

1. Double checking Access key ID and Secret access key configured in aws cli (Running aws configure in command prompt) - They're correct.
2. Trying to list bucket objects using boto3 - It worked successfully. The problem seems to be occuring when trying to download files.
3. Using a chrome plugin to browse bucket contents and download files: [chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/s3/dbcicnhojccpninljlaphamnljlmffdj?hl=en) It works successfully.

The interesting thing is downloading works for some files but not all. I downloaded a file which previously worked before 20 times in a row to see if the error was intermittent. It worked all 20 times. I did the same thing for a file which had not previously worked and it did not download any of the 20 times.

I saw some other posts on stackoverflow saying the api key & access key maybe incorrect. However, I don't believe that to be the case if I was able to list objects and download files (one's which did & did not work through boto3) using the Chrome S3 plugin.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what might be the issue here?

Thank You

Comment: Why do you have `use_ssl=False`?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: I got rid of this error after creating a new set of Access keys

Comment: I am also having this exact same issue... am able to use other boto methods like list_objects_v2, but am unable to download files...

Answer (score 9):

this error occurs when you use wrong/invalid secret key for s3

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this myself. I download on a regular basis about 10 files daily from S3. I noticed that if the file is too large (~8MB), I get the SignatureDoesNotMatch error only for that file, but not the other files which are small in size.
I then tried to use the shell "**aws s3 cp**" CLI command and got the same result. My co-worker suggested using "**aws s3api get-object**", which now works 100% of the time. However, I can't find the equivalent python script, so I'm stuck running the shell script. (**s3.download_file** or **s3.download_fileobj** don't work either.)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the error when my path was not correct. I had double slash // in my path. It removing one of the slashes fixed the error.